# How do I solve these four simultaneous equations?

Tags: systems-of-equations, symmetric-functions

I have been trying hard to solve these equations. There are four equations in total:

$$
\begin{align*}
px^{p-1} + qx^{q-1} \lambda &= 0 \\
py^{p-1} + qy^{q-1} \lambda &= 0 \\
pz^{p-1} + qz^{q-1} \lambda &= 0 \\
x^q + y^q + z^q &= 1
\end{align*}
$$
Here $0<p<q$ and $x,y,z>0$; $\lambda $ is a constant.

Comment: Express $\lambda$ in $3$ different ways. So $x=y=z$. Game over.

Comment: I suppose that this is a Lagrangian problem. André Nicolas gave you the trick.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici yes

Comment: @AndréNicolas Thanks it solved !

Comment: You are welcome. Symmetry is our friend.

Comment: @SophieClad If you have a solution, you can post it as an answer.